How to play an animation only on a specific action?
I have a character model which has multiple animation actions in it (eg. Running, Jumping).
Let's say I want a different object (cube for example) to play an animation like simple moving, but only when the Running action is played.
How do I achieve this in Blender, using NLA strips or something else?
Thanks.

Maybe look into drivers?

This sounds like the XY Problem.
Not sure if this is feasible in Blender as you describe, nor with drivers. Because for this to happen, it would require for Blender to have a system to know "when animation A is playing, play animation B". But Blender doesn't have a logic system that allows you to handle events and conditions.
But I doubt you need that system to begin with, if all you want to do is to have multiple objects playing specific at the same time, the NLA lets you keyframe any strip's influence at any time:

Using that, you could key a strip's influence at 1 when the other action is happening, and at 0 when the other action isn't.
